# How to force an NSWindow to be always active/focused?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have a transparent `NSWindow` that follows the user's screen everywhere he goes (the `NSWindow`stays in front of every app, no matter what, even fullscreen apps).
In that `NSWindow` i have a `mouseDown` event that shows a popup. Let's say i'm on safari in fullscreen mode and i have my Window in front of it, i click on safari and i click again on my Window: nothing happens, the mouseDown doesn't occur. I have to click again so the `mouseDown` event is triggered.
How can i force my `NSWindow` to be always active so i don't have to click it 2x to trigger the `mouseDown` when i click on a background app and click in my window again?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the transparency of your window: It is not fully transparent, is it?

Comment: fully transparent with an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a borderless NSButton instance to your window's view and set your image as the button's image (and as its alternate image, to make it more beautiful), it will work out of the box: Just connect the button's action method to your app delegate (or the object where you want to process the click action). A click on the image (i.e. the button) will then trigger the button's action method, no matter which window is active.

Comment: thank you! that works just the way i wanted! so simple and i didnt notice.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want (it's not quite a window wide setting), but, from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html):

> By default, a mouse-down event in a window that isn’t the key window
>   simply brings the window forward and makes it key; the event isn’t
>   sent to the `NSView` object over which the mouse click occurs. The
>   `NSView` can claim an initial mouse-down event, however, by overriding
>   `acceptsFirstMouse:` to return `YES`.
>
> The argument of this method is the
>   mouse-down event that occurred in the non-key window, which the view
>   object can examine to determine whether it wants to receive the mouse
>   event and potentially become first responder. You want the default
>   behavior of this method in, for example, a control that affects the
>   selected object in a window.
>
> However, in certain cases it’s
>   appropriate to override this behavior, such as for controls that
>   should receive `mouseDown:` messages even when the window is inactive.
>   Examples of controls that support this click-through behavior are the
>   title-bar buttons of a window.

Or you could try fiddling with

```
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

and see if you can handle events in a custom way.

Comment: i did some research in the documentation but i couldnt find anything that worked :/

Comment: DId you try making -acceptsFirstMouse: return YES? That would make the controls immediately usable in your window even if it's not key, which kind of sounds like what you want.

Comment: nop, not working the way i want to. i want the window to be active/focused all the time.

Comment: That's inherently impossible in OSX; you can only have one window be the key window at a time; the best bet would be to replicate the behavior, which is also difficult.

Comment: I don't know if tinkering with -(void)sendEvent would work, but that was my first guess. That way you may be able to directly intercept mouse events, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, hope that will be helpful, This will keep your window always on Top of all applications

```
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[self.window setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel];
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you really should do is use an NSPanel (a floating palette -- a special kind of NSWindow) that will do exactly what you want in a way that's consistent with the OS rather than trying to fight intended behavior.

Here's the NSPanel documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nspanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And here's some helpful and pithy information:

http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSPanel

By default, an NSPanel will disappear when the application is inactive, but you can turn this off.

I apologize for not laying it out more fully ... pressed for time.

Edit:

Note that you can probably get your window to behave as desired simply:

"The NSView can claim an initial mouse-down event, however, by overriding acceptsFirstMouse: to return YES."

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html

You'll need to do this with any NSView subclass to skip the "activation click".

Comment: it's behaving like the nswindow. i have to touch it 2 times to become focused after clicking on a background window :/

Comment: That's default behavior you have to override. If you look at the system character viewer -- an NSPanel -- it accepts the first click and stays in front. See docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html